# updating table information using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have a db with a list of assets and their information pulling from a table "tbl_info" and the solution checks out in sql however it does not update the table after submit.  I don't know where I'm wrong.  I am fairly new to stored procedures and decent w/ sql.

Here's my code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [update_TBL_INFO_4]
(@ASSET_NUMBER  [nvarchar],
 @PORT_NUMBER   [nvarchar],
 @MACHINE_NAME  [nvarchar],
 @TYPE  [nvarchar],
 @BRANCH    [nvarchar],
 @BUILDING_NUMBER   [nvarchar],
 @FLOOR     [nvarchar],
 @ROOM_NUMBER   [nvarchar],
 @TELEPHONE_NUMBER  [nvarchar],
 @USERS     [nvarchar],
 @SERIAL    [nvarchar])

AS 
BEGIN
UPDATE [datasystems].[dbo].[TBL_INFO] 

SET  [ASSET_NUMBER]  = @ASSET_NUMBER,
 [PORT_NUMBER]   = @PORT_NUMBER,
 [MACHINE_NAME]  = @MACHINE_NAME,
 [TYPE]  = @TYPE,
 [BRANCH]    = @BRANCH,
 [BUILDING_NUMBER]   = @BUILDING_NUMBER,
 [FLOOR]     = @FLOOR,
 [ROOM_NUMBER]   = @ROOM_NUMBER,
 [TELEPHONE_NUMBER]  = @TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
 [USERS]     = @USERS,
 [SERIAL]    = @SERIAL 

WHERE 
( [ASSET_NUMBER]     = @ASSET_NUMBER AND
 [PORT_NUMBER]   = @PORT_NUMBER AND
 [MACHINE_NAME]  = @MACHINE_NAME AND
 [TYPE]  = @TYPE AND
 [BRANCH]    = @BRANCH AND
 [BUILDING_NUMBER]   = @BUILDING_NUMBER AND
 [FLOOR]     = @FLOOR AND
 [ROOM_NUMBER]   = @ROOM_NUMBER AND
 [TELEPHONE_NUMBER]  = @TELEPHONE_NUMBER AND
 [USERS]     = @USERS AND
 [SERIAL]    = @SERIAL)
END
GO
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause doesn't make any sense; the only way the record will every get updated is if the data passed in is the same as what is in the table, and the net result will be that nothing changes.  What is the primary key for the table?

Comment: Why all the downvotes for this Q?

Comment: All those `@PORT_NUMBER   [nvarchar],` parameters will be nice and exactly **1 character** long ... when using `(N)VARCHAR`, you should **always** specify an explicit **length** for the parameter!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `WHERE` clause checks *all* of the params, if any of them are different (ie, when you're passing in an updated value), the `WHERE` isn't going to find any records that match.

If you have a Primary Key defined, use that in the `WHERE` clause and update the rest. Otherwise, you may need to pass in the old values as well to find the appropriate match.

**UPDATE:**

With the primary key being `ASSET_NUMBER`, you'd want to update the fields that aren't the primary key, and use the primary key alone in the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
UPDATE 
    [datasystems].[dbo].[TBL_INFO] 
SET  
    [PORT_NUMBER] = @PORT_NUMBER,
    [MACHINE_NAME] = @MACHINE_NAME,
    [TYPE] = @TYPE,
    [BRANCH] = @BRANCH,
    [BUILDING_NUMBER] = @BUILDING_NUMBER,
    [FLOOR] = @FLOOR,
    [ROOM_NUMBER] = @ROOM_NUMBER,
    [TELEPHONE_NUMBER] = @TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
    [USERS] = @USERS,
    [SERIAL] = @SERIAL 
WHERE 
    [ASSET_NUMBER] = @ASSET_NUMBER
```

Comment: primary key is asset_number

Comment: @user1913068 - then change your `WHERE` clause to `WHERE ( [ASSET_NUMBER] = @ASSET_NUMBER )`. Not trying to be rude, but for someone "decent at SQL", you might want to brush up on your SQL, this is pretty basic.

Comment: it's fine i expect critisizm since i was thrown into this position and given a book to read on these things in a timeframe of a month, i've got a working site in 1 week with abilities to pull info etc and i've never done this before so i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Per the comment someone else had made on the question, have you updated your definitions from `NVARCHAR` to something with a longer length, like `NVARCHAR(255)`? When `NVARCHAR` is used without a length specified in a definition, it defaults to 1 character - so if the values have more than one character, you'll need to declare your parameters with a length in order to get a match in the `WHERE` clause (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)